# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\TwoFactorAuth\Api\UserConfigManagerInterface while running Integration Tests

Tags: phpunit, magento2.4.1

Trying to [Run all integration tests](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/test/integration/integration_test_execution.html#run-all-integration-tests) using `../../../vendor/bin/phpunit` command.

Getting an error -

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
> Magento\TwoFactorAuth\Api\UserConfigManagerInterface

```
[Progress: 1276 / 1762]
Module 'Magento_TwoFactorAuth':
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\TwoFactorAuth\Api\UserConfigManagerInterface in /var/www/html/ce241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/ce241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#1 /var/www/html/ce241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#2 /var/www/html/ce241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get()
#3 /var/www/html/ce241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#4 /var/www/html/ce241/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchApplier.php(149): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#5 /var/www/html/ce241/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1081): Magento\F in /var/www/html/ce241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

I have disabled `Magento_TwoFactorAuth` module from main `app/etc/config.php`.
No other additional modules installed.
Already checked permissions and ownership's of the respective directories.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this resolved?

Comment: @Laura I had to re-enable `Magento_TwoFactorAuth` while executing integration test on my local. But you can use this `https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth/tree/master/Test` and add some integration test to `\Test\Integration` & make it work in that way. MFTF already there.

Answer (score 1):

For me I have the same issue if I have run setup:di:compile (i.e. generated code). The solution is to remove generated code. Enabling the module clears generated code, which is probably the reason why that seemingly works - integration tests ignore settings in app/etc/config.php.